# Clear the selectboxes on click of a button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, devextreme

I am using Devextreme in my Angular application and have three dx-selectbox in the component, I am trying to clear all the three dropdown selection on click of the button like clear. I am not finding a way to do the selectbox clear or reset

[HTML]

```
     <dx-box direction="row" width="90%" style="padding-top: 3vw">  
    <dxi-item  [ratio]="1" >  
      <dx-select-box [dataSource]="shipToData" (onValueChanged)="onShipToChanged($event)"  [stylingMode]="'underlined'" style="width: 20vw" ></dx-select-box>  
    </dxi-item>  
    <dxi-item  [ratio]="1" >  
      <dx-select-box [dataSource]="poData" (onValueChanged)="onPOChanged($event)"  [stylingMode]="'underlined'" style="width: 20vw"  ></dx-select-box>  
    </dxi-item>  
    <dxi-item  [ratio]="1">  
      <dx-select-box [dataSource]="salesOrderData" (onValueChanged)="onSalesOrderChanged($event)"  [stylingMode]="'underlined'" style="width: 20vw" ></dx-select-box>  
     </dxi-item>  
 </dx-box>
```

And In my component  I have the code like below

[TypeScript]

```
onShipToChanged(e)  
  {  
    this.selectedShipTo = e.value;  
    .......  
    e.value = "";  
  }  

  onPOChanged(d)  
  {  
    this.selectedPO = d.value;  
    ......  
    d.value="";  
  }  

  onSalesOrderChanged(g)  
  {  
    this.selectedSO = g.value;  
   ........  
    g.value ="";  
  }  

  clear(){  
    debugger;  
this.selectedSO ="";  
  this.selectedPO = "";  
  this.selectedShipTo = ="";  
  }  

  onValueChanged(s:any)  
  {  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of button, call `onClick()` and set,

```
this.shipToData = [];
this.poData = [];
this.salesOrderData = [];
```

Comment: I dont want to clear the datasource instead I need to just clear the selection so the users can select again

Comment: then add [value] attribute of select box and set a variable to it. Then set that variable to null or " " on button selection.

Answer (score 0):

The e parameter is an emitted copy of the event object therefore it has no references to the original event and because of this changing it has no effect.

If you want to clear your selection, you'd have to clear your data sources.

Comment: I dont want to clear the datasource instead I need to just clear the selection so the users can select again

Comment: then add [value]="myBoxValuePlaceholdername" attributes to your boxes and set myBoxValuePlaceholdername = ''; when needed.